# Unlist and retain list names intact in R

Tags: r

I have data similar to these:

```
listdata <- list(matrix(c(1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3),nrow=2,ncol=4),matrix(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),nrow=2))
names(listdata) <- c("5555","5566")

RowData <- lapply(listdata, "rownames<-", c("from","to"))

FrameData <- lapply(RowData, function(x) as.data.frame(x))
```

Now I do unlist the list as wanted, but the list names are changed. How to preserve the list names?

```
as.matrix(unlist(FrameData))
```

Wanted output without the `.V11` column names:

```
       [,1]
 5555    1
 5555    1
 5555    1
 5555    1
 5555    3
 5555    3
 5555    3
  .....
  .....
```

EDIT: This is not good example since in my case I don't have the `5555.V1` but only adds only number: 1,2,3,4... So what I have actually is this:

```
    [,1]
 55551    1
 55552    1
 55553    1
 55554    1
 55555    3
 .... 
 555536   3
 555537   3
  .....

 Rname <- rownames(listdata)
 strtrim(Rname, nchar(Rname)-1)
```

the problem is that the numbering is increasing...so the problem is to define `y`  nchar(x)-y

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)

melt(FrameData)
#Using  as id variables
#Using  as id variables
#   variable value   L1
#1        V1     1 5555
#2        V1     1 5555
#3        V2     1 5555
#4        V2     1 5555
#5        V3     3 5555
#6        V3     3 5555
#7        V4     3 5555
#8        V4     3 5555
#9        V1     1 5566
#10       V1     1 5566
#11       V2     1 5566
#12       V2     1 5566
#13       V3     2 5566
#14       V3     2 5566
#15       V4     2 5566
#16       V4     2 5566
```

Answer (score 3):

You can rename you rownames like this For example:

```
mm <- as.matrix(unlist(FrameData))
rownames(mm) <- sub('[.].*','',rownames(mm))
```

Comment: This works, however I didn't expect this kind of solution :) so please see my EDIT. I already tried to remove the rowname numering.

Comment: I'm still strungling with it! On the end your solution may help, how I would udjust the `sub` for `5555.1` ...`5555.2` etc. just dot and numering after, which increases with sample size. Thank you!

Comment: I don't get exactly your point. If you want to remove the "V" you can do something like this `sub('V','',rownames(mm))`.

Comment: No, I was looking for removing everything after the dot and dot included. I have figured it out already: `sub("*\\.[0-9]","",rownames(mm))`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue but my rownames were urls so I had couldn't alter the naming convention, so here is a solution that worked for me

```
names(listdata)<- paste(L1,"|||", sep = "")
df <- data.frame("variable" = (unlist(listdata, recursive = FALSE, use.names = TRUE)))
df1<-data.frame("variable"=df$variable, "values" = values "L1" = row.names(df))  
df1$L1<- sapply(strsplit(df1$L1, split='|||', fixed=TRUE), function(x) (x[1]))
```